# Create an image slider for multiple diffrent galleries in ASP NET

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core, razor, frontend

I have a map where anyone can add a custom marker with info and images.
I want to create for each marker with more than 1 image, a slider.

Now each marker looks something like that:
[image]

I want that if there are multiple images for lets say for 'n' markers, I want to make all the images hidden except the first one and make a slider for each one of them.

### This is the code now:

```
foreach (var _Data in Model)
    {
        <div class="popup" id="overlay-container-@_Data.Id">
            <div class="overlay">
                <div class="content"> @*Content <-Text->*@
                    <div class="close-btn" onclick="togglePopup(@_Data.Id)">&times;</div>
                    <h3><u>Category</u>: @_Data.category</h3><br />
                    <h5><u>Title</u>: @_Data.title</h5>

                    <u>Description</u>: <br /> <textarea disabled cols="50" rows="10" style="resize:none; background: none; border:hidden" class="accept-policy"> @_Data.remarks </textarea>   <br />

                    <b>Urgence</b>: @_Data.statUrgence <br />

                    <br />

                    <div id="slideshow-container" style="height:200px; width:380px; display: flex; overflow: hidden;"> @*The Images*@

                        @{
                            string @path = @_Data.path;
                            string ImgPath = @path.Substring(@path.IndexOf("Files") - 1, (@path.Length - (@path.IndexOf("Files") - 1)));
                            string[] ImgPathArray = ImgPath.Split('\\');

                            string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@path); // _Data.path

                            foreach (var file in filePaths)
                            {
                                var temp = file;

                                List<string> set1 = path.Split('\\').Distinct().ToList();
                                List<string> set2 = temp.Split('\\').Distinct().ToList();

                                var diff = set2.Count() > set1.Count() ? set2.Except(set1).ToList() : set1.Except(set2).ToList();

                                
                                <img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; width: auto;"
                                     src="~/@string.Join("/", ImgPathArray).Remove(0,1)/@string.Join("", diff)" />
                            }
                        }
                    </div>
                <br />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    

    <script> @*Display markers*@
            markers = new ol.layer.Vector({
                source: new ol.source.Vector(),
                style: new ol.style.Style({
                    image: new ol.style.Icon({
                        anchor: [0.5, 1],
                        src: 'https://ucarecdn.com/4b516de9-d43d-4b75-9f0f-ab0916bd85eb/marker.png' // => https://app.uploadcare.com/projects/c05bbeb5e1a61e862903/files/7110cd57-b0ee-4833-bcd1-ff0343dd01cc/?limit=100&ordering=-datetime_uploaded
                    })
                })
            });

             map.addLayer(markers);

            var marker = new ol.Feature(new ol.geom.Point([parseFloat(@_Data.coordLat), parseFloat(@_Data.coordLong)]));
            marker.setId(@_Data.Id);
            //console.log(marker.getId());
            markers.getSource().addFeature(marker);

    </script>
}

<style> @*Style for the marker's popuop*@
        .popup .overlay {
            position: fixed;
            top: 0px;
            left: 0px;
            width: 100vw;
            height: 100vh;
            background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
            z-index: 1;
            display: none;
        }

        .popup .content {
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0);
            background: #fff;
            width: auto;
            height: auto;
            z-index: 2;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 20px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        .popup .close-btn {
            position: absolute;
            right: 20px;
            top: 20px;
            width: 30px;
            height: 30px;
            background: #222;
            color: #fff;
            font-size: 25px;
            font-weight: 600;
            line-height: 23.5px;
            text-align: center;
            border-radius: 50%;
        }

        .popup.active .overlay {
            display: block;
        }

        .popup.active .content {
            transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
        }
    </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Bootstrap Image slider (carousel)`.

For example, you have a list of image paths：

```
@{
    List<string> imagePath = new List<string>() { "/images/img1.jpg", "/images/img2.jpg", "/images/img3.jpg" };
}
```

Then you can use carousel to load images:

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false" data-pause="hover">
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            @for (var i=0;i<imagePath.Count();i++)
            {
                var showClass = (i == 0 ? "active":"");
                var path = imagePath[i];
                <div class="item @showClass">
                    <div class="carousel-content">
                        <div style="margin: 0 auto">
                            <p>
                                <img src="@path" />
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
        </div>
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only"> Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
    .carousel-content {
        color: black;
        display: flex;
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.carousel').carousel();
    });
</script>
```

Result:
[image]

If you want to have a carousel effect, set `data-interval="2000"` (2s switch).

Is this what you want?

Comment: Yes. but will the JavaScript will work for multiple markers that have different image groups?

Comment: You load the image through the path. After clicking the corresponding marker, call `$('.carousel').carousel();` to realize the slider of the corresponding image for different markers. What kind of effect do you want? Can you describe it in detail? @David